# Tiles does not include correctly the jsp-s

Tags: tiles

I have a problem with tiles 2.2.2.
It seems that the jsp-s aren't read as they are supposed to.
My tiles.xml looks like this:

```
<definition name="notLoggedInLayout" template="WEB-INF/pages/template/templatenotloggedin.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="css" value="css/style.css" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="WEB-INF/pages/template/notloggedinheader.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="WEB-INF/pages/template/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="login" extends="notLoggedInLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Login" />
    <put-attribute name="navigation" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="WEB-INF/pages/login/login.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and my templatenotloggedin.jsp looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib
    uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    prefix="tiles"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>
<link
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="<tiles:getAsString name='css'/>"
/>
</head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the formed page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>
<link
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="css/style.css"
/>
</head>
<body>
    WEB-INF/pages/template/notloggedinheader.jsp
    WEB-INF/pages/login/login.jspsadsdf
    WEB-INF/pages/template/footer.jsp
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my answer minutes after posting this question.
The problem is that the jsp path needs to have a slash before the path.

this:

```
<put-attribute name="body" value="WEB-INF/pages/login/login.jsp" />
```

becomes this:

```
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/login/login.jsp" />
```